# kubernetes envFrom: how to load variables located into pod filesystem file

Tags: kubernetes

I need to populate an env file located into pod filesystem filled by an init container previously.

I look up `envFrom` [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/federation/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1_envfromsource) but I've not been able to figure out how to use it and I've been able to find some relevant examples in internet.

Guess an init container creates a file on `/etc/secrets/secrets.env`, so the pod container spec has to look up on `/etc/secrets/secrets.env` in order to populate env variables.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I need to get this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to reference any filesystem component to populate an environment variable using the PodSpec, because it creates a chicken-and-egg problem: kubernetes cannot create the filesystem without a complete PodSpec, but it cannot resolve variables in the PodSpec without access to the Pod's filesystem

If `/etc/secrets` is a `volume` that the `initContainer` and the normal `container` share, then you can supersede the `command:` of your `container` to source that into its environment before running the actual command, but that is as close as you're going to get:

```
containers:
- name: my-app
  command:
  - bash
  - -ec
  - |
    . /etc/secrets/secrets.env
    ./bin/run-your-server-command-here
```